# android how to get the path name of the drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, pathname

How do I get the path name to the drawables in my resource folder?  I am trying to get the image in my resource folder and pass it to the function to decode it.

the path "android.resource://com.myapp.example/"+ R.drawable.image"  didnt works.

```
 Bitmap bitmap;

 File image = new File("android.resource://com.myapp.example/"+ R.drawable.image);

 bitmap.decodeFile(image);


public Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: why would yo want to access the bitmap that way?

Comment: I want to use the function DecodeFile as it need the parameter File.  Is there other way to use that function?

Answer (score 6):

BitmapFactory has function to decode resources:

```
Bitmap BitmapFactory.decodeResource (Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

Example:

```
bitmap.decodeFile(R.drawable.image);

public Bitmap decodeFile(int resId) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId, o);
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId, o2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant get the path because the resource folder is compiled into the apk, but you can grab the resource like this:

```
Resources rsrc= getResources();
Drawable drawable= rsrc.getDrawable(R.drawable.datImage);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rsrc,drawable, opts);
```